# Initializing table types in Oracle

Tags: oracle, types

I have such simple procedure  and TYPETEST table type.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TESTPROCEDURE (dayName out TYPETEST )IS 
BEGIN
dayName(1):='Monday';
dayname(2):='1';
dayname(3):='good';
END TESTPROCEDURE; 
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TYPETEST AS TABLE OF  varchar2(50);
```

it compiles normally, but when I run it, it gives such exception:

> "ORA-06531:Reference to uninitialized collection".

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize dayName and extend it (each time by 1 or at the beginning by 3):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTPROCEDURE (dayName out TYPETEST )IS
BEGIN
  dayName := typetest();
  dayName.extend(3);
  dayName(1):='Monday';
  dayname(2):='1';
  dayname(3):='good';
END TESTPROCEDURE;
```

Test:

```
declare 
  t typetest;
begin 
  TESTPROCEDURE(t); 
  for i in 1..t.count() loop
    dbms_output.put_line(t(i));
  end loop;
end;
```

Output:

```
Monday
1
good
```

Answer (score 0):

With Oracle Database 18c you can use [qualified expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-4B379569-4068-4DB1-9D69-E706F4AC5758).

```
declare
  type typetest is table of varchar2(50);
  t typetest := typetest('Monday', '1', 'good');
begin
  for i in 1 .. t.count() loop
    dbms_output.put_line(t(i));
  end loop;
end;
```

This shortens your initialization to one line.